# Reverse Engineer sequence diagram in StarUML

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, staruml

I am in the process of reverse engineering an existing java project. I am using StarUML to generate the class diagrams.

I would like to know how I can generate a package diagram, package dependency diagram and sequence diagram from existing code in StarUML? I would be much interested in sequence diagram if not the others. Could you please let me know about it?

I would also like to know if you have come across any other better open source tool that does this job. Thanks a bunch for your time.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not familiar with `StarUML` ... well there is a tool named [BinaryDoc](https://www.binarydoc.org/) looks can generate the desired diagram. BinaryDoc is trying to generate the diagrams based on the meta data in the binary files, like Java `.jar`/`.jmd` and `.class` files.

> class diagrams

Here is an sample of class diagram for [java.lang.ClassLoader](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/classfile?classfilelocation=java.lang.classloader)

[image]

> package dependency diagram

Here is an sample of Java package diagram for [java.sql](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/package?package=java.sql)

[image]